# bash if statement help

Tags: bash, shell, for

I am currently using 2 scripts.  1 script to filter the files by year.  2nd script into which sits inside the year subfolders to filter by month # (01-12).

Is there something that would be better than what I have below?

All of the files are in 1 directory:

SOURCE: ./tape_backup/sync1/* (1.4 million files)
TARGET: ./tape_backup/<1990 - 2019>/<01-12>/ (Organized by year/month)

The syntax of the filename: A1000_T195_R256393_**D120498**094600

_D = Unimporant

D   = Date start

1-2 = month

3-4 = Day (unimportant)

5-6 = Year

7-* = Timestamp (unimportant)

Hence why I do the whole *D????98*

Something that would read like this:

for f in ./sync1 
     do
      (check the month and year, then mv it into the month
      and years folder /)
     done

I'm on Cygwin and the server 2012 r2

```
#C:/cygwin/bin/bash
for filename in ./* ; do
 if [[ $filename == *D??90 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1990/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??91 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1991/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??92 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1992/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??93 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1993/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??94 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1994/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??95 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1995/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??96 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1996/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??97 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1997/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??98 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1998/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??99 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/1999/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??00 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2000/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??01 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2001/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??02 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2002/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??03 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2003/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??04 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2004/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??05 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2005/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??06 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2006/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??07 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2007/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??08 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2008/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??09 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2009/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??10 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2010/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??11 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2011/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??12 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2012/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??13 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2013/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??14 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2014/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??15 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2015/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??16 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2016/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??17 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2017/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??18 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2018/

 elif [[ $filename == *D??19 ]] ; then
      mv $filename /cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/2019/
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to be calling `mv` 1.4 million times, it's going to be slow - no way around that. But you already know the pattern of the filenames, so why not batch them, calling multiple files with a single `mv`:

```
for yy in {1990..2019}
do
    y=${yy#[0-9][0-9]}  # remove first two digits of year
    mv ./*D??"$y" "/cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/$yy"
done
```

Or, if this runs into "argument length exceeded" errors, use `xargs`:

```
for yy in {1990..2019}
do
   y=${yy#[0-9][0-9]}
   printf "%s\0" ./*D??"$y" |   # NUL-delimited filenames for xargs -0
       xargs -0 -r mv -t "/cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/$yy"
done
```

Comment: I updated my OP - hope it makes more sense... THANK YOU!

Comment: I got your first one to work.  With some modification, perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Doing 1.4 million calls to `mv` to move things between different drives will be slow.  Try calling `mv` fewer times.

Assuming that the `??` in your pattern is supposed to match the century:

```bash
for year in {1990..2019}; do
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*D$year" \
        -exec mv -t "/cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/invoices/1/$year/" {} +
done
```

This would loop over all relevant years.  For each year, it will execute a `find` command that would move as many files that match the given pattern as possible at once, in batches.

The code assumes that you use GNU `mv` (for the `-t` option) and GNU `find` (or any `find` that has `-maxdepth`) together with `bash`.  If your source directory does not contain any subdirectories, then you may remove `-maxdepth 1` from the command.

Comment: I updated my OP - I hoep it makes more sense!  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just so everyone knows - I used this option, by muru.  I actually tried both options posted above.

With a slight modification... I was doing about 3 files a second with my original 50 lines of code.  Now I'm doing about 30 - 50 a second.

for yy in {1998..2018}
do
    y=${yy#[0-9][0-9]}  # remove first two digits of year
    mv -v ./sync1/*_D????$y* "/cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/tape_backup/$yy"
    #mv -v ./sync1/*_D????'$y*' "/cygdrive/d/RAID5/RAID200/tape_backup/$yy"
done

:)